# User-defined section overlapped with .bss section when compiling linux kernel

Tags: linux, riscv, lds

I'm learning the operating system, and I'm trying to use vmlinux.lds to lay out my code to specific locations.
The following is my vmlinux.lds:

```
OUTPUT_ARCH( "riscv" )
ENTRY( _start )
MEMORY {
  ram (wxa!ri) : ORIGIN = 0x0000000080000000, LENGTH = 20M
  ramv (wxa!ri) : ORIGIN = 0xffffffc000000000, LENGTH = 4096M
}
PHDRS {
  text PT_LOAD;
  rodata PT_LOAD;
  data PT_LOAD;
  user_program PT_LOAD;
  bss PT_LOAD;
}
SECTIONS {
 . = 0xffffffc000000000;
 .text : 
 {
  PROVIDE(text_start = .);
  *(.text.init)
  *(.text.entry)
  *(.text .text.*)
  PROVIDE(text_end = .);
 } >ramv AT>ram :text

 .rodata : ALIGN(0x1000) 
 {
  PROVIDE(rodata_start = .);
  *(.srodata .srodata.*)
  *(.rodata .rodata.*)
  PROVIDE(rodata_end = .);
 } >ramv AT>ram :rodata

 .data : ALIGN(0x1000) 
 {
  PROVIDE(data_start = .);
  *(.sdata .sdata.*)
  *(.data .data.*)
  PROVIDE(data_end = .);
 } >ramv AT>ram :data

 .user_program : ALIGN(0x1000)
 {
  PROVIDE(user_program_start = .);
  *(.user_program.entry)
 }>ramv AT>ram :user_program

 .bss : ALIGN(0x1000) 
 {
  PROVIDE(bss_start = .);
  *(.sbss .sbss.*)
  *(.bss .bss.*)
  PROVIDE(bss_end = .);
 } >ramv AT>ram :bss


 
 . = ALIGN(0x1000);
 . += 0x1000;
 init_stack_top = .;
 . += 0x1000;
 stack_top = .;

 _end = .;
}
```

The section ".user_program" is expected to be at 0xffffffc000004000 and the length is 0x5000. I use objdump to check this, and I find that the ".user_program" section is overlayed by the ".bss" section. And after objcopy, the ".user_program" section disappear.

This is the result of objdump:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS         ffffffc000000000  00001000
       0000000000001a64  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     8
  [ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS         ffffffc000002000  00003000
       0000000000000213  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4096
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS         ffffffc000003000  00004000
       0000000000000078  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     4096
  [ 4] .user_program     PROGBITS         ffffffc000004000  00005000
       0000000000005000  0000000000000000           0     0     4096
  [ 5] .bss              NOBITS           ffffffc000004000  00005000
       0000000000000238  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     4096
```

this is the result of "ls -l". The size of "Image" refers that it only contains sections ".text" ".todata" and ".data".

```
# ls -l arch/riscv/boot/Image 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12408 Oct  9 09:36 arch/riscv/boot/Image
```